# MySQL Union Performance Issue

Tags: mysql, performance, union

I have 3 tables (SuccessOrder, FailedOrder, and PendingOrder) with same columns. Each table is having more than 2 million records. I need to combine all the data from these 3 tables and sort them by CreatedDate to display in my portal. I am using UNION ALL to combine the result from all tables.

If I execute each subquery, getting the result in 1 or 2 seconds. If I execute the whole query (3 subqueries with UNION ALL), it is taking more than 5 minutes.

```
select * from (
select * from SuccessOrder
UNION ALL
select * from FailedOrder
UNION ALL
select * from PendingOrder
) t order by t.ID;
```

Is there any alternative to UNION ALL ?

Is it possible to create view from 3 queries without UNION ALL ?

Following are the Individual and union queries tested from workbench. I don't see much difference between **UNION ALL** and **UNION ALL - ORDER BY**

**First Query**

***Duration/Fetch Time***: 2.182 sec / 1.513 sec

```
SELECT  col1, col2, ...
    FROM  CompleteTxn ct
    left outer join  CompleteItem ci  ON (ct.Id = ci.TxnId)
    left outer join  ItemDispute id  ON (ct.Id = id.TxnId and  ci.Id = id.ItemId )
    left outer join  Merchant mc  ON (ct.MerchantId = mc.Id)
    left outer join  AdditionalTxnInfo addti  ON (ct.Id = addti.TxnId)
    where  (ct.PartitionKey>=55 AND  ct.PartitionKey<=56 )
      and  ( ct.TxnCompleteTime >= '2016-08-01 17:00:00'
        and  ct.TxnCompleteTime <= '2016-08-09 17:00:00'
           )
      and  ct.MnoId in (22,24,25,23,26,220,221,200,223,224,320, 400)
      and  ct.Status in (1,2,3,4,5);
```

**Second Query**

***Duration/Fetch Time***: 0.279 sec / 0.861 sec

```
SELECT  col1, col2, ...
    FROM  FailedOrder ct
    left outer join  FailedItem ci  ON (ct.Id = ci.TxnId)
    left outer join  ItemDispute id  ON (ct.Id = id.TxnId and  ci.Id = id.ItemId )
    left outer join  Merchant mc  ON (ct.MerchantId = mc.Id)
    left outer join  AdditionalTxnInfo addti  ON (ct.Id = addti.TxnId)
    where  (ct.PartitionKey>=55 AND  ct.PartitionKey<=56 )
      and  ( ct.TxnCompleteTime >= '2016-08-01 17:00:00'
        and  ct.TxnCompleteTime <= '2016-08-09 17:00:00'
           )
      and  ct.MnoId in (22,24,25,23,26,220,221,200,223,224,320, 400);
```

**Union All withour order by**

***Duration/Fetch Time***: 104.802 sec / 0.00027 sec

```
select  *
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  col1, col2, ...
            FROM  FailedOrder ct
            left outer join  FailedItem ci  ON (ct.Id = ci.TxnId)
            left outer join  ItemDispute id  ON (ct.Id = id.TxnId
                      and  ci.Id = id.ItemId 
                          )
            left outer join  Merchant mc  ON (ct.MerchantId = mc.Id)
            left outer join  AdditionalTxnInfo addti  ON (ct.Id = addti.TxnId)
    where  (ct.PartitionKey>=55 AND  ct.PartitionKey<=56 )
      and  ( ct.TxnCompleteTime >= '2016-08-01 17:00:00'
        and  ct.TxnCompleteTime <= '2016-08-09 17:00:00'
           )
      and  ct.MnoId in (22,24,25,23,26,220,221,200,223,224,320, 400)
              and  ct.Status in (1,2,3,4,5)
    UNION  ALL 
        SELECT  col1, col2, ...
            FROM  CompleteTxn ct
            left outer join  CompleteItem ci  ON (ct.Id = ci.TxnId)
            left outer join  ItemDispute id  ON (ct.Id = id.TxnId
                      and  ci.Id = id.ItemId
                          )
            left outer join  Merchant mc  ON (ct.MerchantId = mc.Id)
            left outer join  AdditionalTxnInfo addti  ON (ct.Id = addti.TxnId)
    where  (ct.PartitionKey>=55 AND  ct.PartitionKey<=56 )
      and  ( ct.TxnCompleteTime >= '2016-08-01 17:00:00'
        and  ct.TxnCompleteTime <= '2016-08-09 17:00:00'
           )
      and  ct.MnoId in (22,24,25,23,26,220,221,200,223,224,320, 400)        ) t ;
```

**Union All with order by**

***Duration/Fetch Time***: 104.895 sec / 0.00028 sec

select * FROM (

SELECT col1, col2, ...  FROM FailedOrder ct left outer join FailedItem ci ON (ct.Id = ci.TxnId) left outer join ItemDispute id ON (ct.Id = id.TxnId and ci.Id = id.ItemId) left outer join Merchant mc ON (ct.MerchantId = mc.Id) left outer join AdditionalTxnInfo addti ON (ct.Id = addti.TxnId)   where (ct.PartitionKey>=55 AND ct.PartitionKey<=56) and ( ct.TxnCompleteTime >= '2016-08-01 17:00:00' and ct.TxnCompleteTime <= '2016-08-09 17:00:00')  and  ct.MnoId in (22,24,25,23,26,220,221,200,223,224,320,400)  and  ct.Status in (1,2,3,4,5)

UNION ALL

SELECT col1, col2, ...  FROM CompleteTxn ct left outer join CompleteItem ci ON (ct.Id = ci.TxnId) left outer join ItemDispute id ON (ct.Id = id.TxnId and ci.Id = id.ItemId) left outer join Merchant mc ON (ct.MerchantId = mc.Id) left outer join AdditionalTxnInfo addti ON (ct.Id = addti.TxnId)   where (ct.PartitionKey>=55 AND ct.PartitionKey<=56) and ( ct.TxnCompleteTime >= '2016-08-01 17:00:00' and ct.TxnCompleteTime <= '2016-08-09 17:00:00')  and  ct.MnoId in (22,24,25,23,26,220,221,200,223,224,320,400)

) t ORDER BY id desc;

Comment: If you remove the `order by t.ID` then I guess it would be much faster otherwise it's supposed to take time.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to retrieve six million records at once? That's three table scans. Indexing will not be much use here.

Comment: We are not retrieving 6 million records at once. We have conditions on each subquery. We need to check the search the from these 3 tables and order them by selected field (Mostly ID) and display first 100 records to the user with pagination

Answer (score 0):

As per my assumption you are dealing with Huge data almost 6 million records.

1)when comparing to Union , Union All is far more faster

2)you are taking all the select statements into Derived table .

3)Again you are doing ORDER BY on ID (**performance Issue** )

It will give huge performance impact if you do Order by on Huge Data.

All the Result will get Ordered in Sequential manner so Definitely SORTING COST Percentage will be increased

```
select Col1,Col2 from SuccessOrder
UNION ALL
select Col1,Col2  from FailedOrder
UNION ALL
select Col1,Col2  from PendingOrder
```

Comment: seriously can you please draft this one in your question @rkvegiraju

Comment: I executed my queries in the workbench and added the duration of each query in the description. don't see much difference between **UNION ALL** and **UNION ALL - ORDER BY**

Answer (score 0):

Your `order by` is most likely the culprit here. You're essentially ordering your whole database after select, and depending how its indexed, that can take a long time.

You could:

- make sure the tables are indexed on what you order by (important)
- remove the order by alltogether

I don't think that the `union all` cost comes close to the cost of sorting all that data.

Comment: Since the ordered columns belong to a union that may contain duplicates, doesn't that mean the index on the primary key is unusable? There would have to be a new index built on the union, which to my knowledge cannot be done. Is that correct?

Comment: When you do an order by without a union you're still ordering one whole table.

Answer (score 0):

I will plead ignorance as to why union is so long compared to the selects, someone far smarter than me will need to testify to that.  I repeated the results you obtained with my own database with a similar overhead. This being said, if your sorting off a subselect, you lose the indexing of the tables

```
select * from (
(select * from SuccessOrder order by ID limit 100)
UNION ALL
(select * from FailedOrder  order by ID limit 100)
UNION ALL
(select * from PendingOrder order by ID limit 100)
) t order by t.ID desc limit 100;
```

would take advantage of the indexing and return your 100 without too much overhead.  If you wanted all 6 million rows paged... that's slightly different, but a straight up last 100 is reasonable, but this depends on how your `id` column is generated, if its the equivalent of a record number, this answer helps no one.

Comment: LIMIT on subquery worked for me. I got the result in 0.53 sec. 

I have 2 more cases. 

1. Need count of total records for pagination

2. Sometimes, I need to export the data to Excel files. 

Linit will not work in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these tips may help:

- You don't need the outer `SELECT`
- Don't return millions of rows; process them in MySQL, then deliver only the ones you need, or summarize the you need.
- If you are going to use only the first few, see [*documentation on `UNION`*](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)
- Minimize the number of columns to return.  The extra bulk of extra columns is part of the slowdown.
- Change `(ct.PartitionKey>=55 AND  ct.PartitionKey<=56 )` to `ct.PartitionKey IN (55,56)` if practical
- In `ct.TxnCompleteTime <= '2016-08-09 17:00:00'`, change `<=` to `<`.
- Have an index with one of the INs first and `TxnCompleteTime` second.
- Consider putting all the data in one table.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.